# In R language package `ggmosaic`, how to add weight percent label to the columns

Tags: r, ggmosaic

In package `ggmosaic`, how to add weight percent label  to the columns ? I want to add the percent value of each column (every column totla percent equalt 100%). Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

ggplot(data = titanic) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived)) +
  geom_mosaic_text(size=5,aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ggplot_build` to calculate the percentage per class of each total count values like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

p <- ggplot(data = titanic) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived)) +
  geom_mosaic_text(size=5,aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived))

p + geom_text(data = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] %>% 
                group_by(x__Class) %>%
                mutate(pct = .wt/sum(.wt)*100), 
              aes(x = (xmin+xmax)/2, y = (ymin+ymax)/2, label=round(pct, 2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks , this is very useful to know  'ggplot_build(p)'

Comment: Hi @anderwyang, Yes `ggplot_build` can be very useful in some situations!